# Prompting user to re-enter integers until binary number is entered

Tags: java, loops

I am new with JAVA (computer programming by the way). The following program checks if the input is binary or not. And it should prompt user to re-enter integers until binary number is entered. But this program is doing exactly opposite.
It is asking me to re-enter integers if input is binary, and the program terminates when non-binary is entered.
I need a serious help, please.[Here is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPUeO.png)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int value, userValue;
    int binaryDigit = 0, notBinaryDigit = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter positive integers: ");

        userValue = scan.nextInt();
        value = userValue;

        while (userValue > 0) {
            if ((userValue % 10 == 0) || (userValue % 10 == 1)) {
                binaryDigit++;
            } else {
                notBinaryDigit++;
            }

            userValue = userValue / 10;

        }

        if (notBinaryDigit > 0) {
            System.out.println(value + " is a not a Binary Number.");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println(value + " is  a  Binary Number.");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `if (!((userValue % 10 == 0) || (userValue % 10 == 1))` -- Negate the statement.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger? That is the place to start. If you don't know how to use the debugger, take the time NOW to start learning.  It is a required skill if you are going to do any coding.

Comment: I don't know what you're planning to use the binary value for, but you should consider that binary numbers can begin with one or more zeroes. If you store the value in an `int` the leading zeroes will be removed. Also consider what happens when a user enters a very large binary number that when parsed as an `int` exceeds the maximum value an `int` can represent. Also consider that you're not handling the scenario where the user enters text instead of numbers. Lastly, in general you should break up your logic into units by creating small easy to understand methods this will simplify the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be too late for the answer. But the code can be simplified much if you make use of the method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter positive integers: ");
            int userValue = scan.nextInt();
            if (isBinary(userValue)) {
                System.out.println(userValue + " is a Binary Number.");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println(userValue + " is  a not Binary Number.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isBinary(int input) {
        while (input > 0) {
            if ((input % 10 != 0) && (input % 10 != 1)) {
                return false;
            }
            input = input / 10;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change your code**

from this

```
  if (notBinaryDigit > 0) {
        System.out.println(value + " is a not a Binary Number.");
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println(value + " is  a  Binary Number.");

    }
```

to this

```
 if (notBinaryDigit > 0) {
        System.out.println(value + " is a not a Binary Number.");
        notBinaryDigit--;
    } if(binaryDigit >0 {
        System.out.println(value + " is  a  Binary Number.");
 binaryDigit--;
  break;
    }
```

**and it will ask for values and tell if it is binary or not and it terminates if it is binary**

Comment: Thank you for help!

Answer (score -1):

Error coming due to Scanner class.
you can run your program and check your logic by removing the Scanner class like this.

public class Test{

```
public static void main(String []args){

    int value, userValue=34;
    int binaryDigit = 0, notBinaryDigit = 0;
    value = userValue;

    while (userValue > 0) {
        if ((userValue % 10 == 0) || (userValue % 10 == 1)) {
                binaryDigit++;
            } else {
                notBinaryDigit++;
            }

            userValue = userValue / 10;

        }

        if (notBinaryDigit > 0) {
            System.out.println(value + " is a not a Binary Number.");

        } else {
            System.out.println(value + " is  a  Binary Number.");

        }
}
```

}

Comment: there is no error due to Scanner class,you have to import it first

Comment: Brother, I have imported but Some time due to ide configuration It comes. First, check what's the real problem then do whatever you want to do.

Comment: ide config is causing problem in your computer and not related with the  problem above